# PHP session_starts creates read only sessions? (folder is writable, sessions are created!)

Tags: php, session, file-permissions, session-state, permission-denied

This is the error I'm getting once I refresh the page:

> session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/home/user/tmp/sess_9582f1d2ca7c1253e8f214943c58abf9, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)

So, on first view of the page, the session file is written correctly. But it only has a read attribute:

```
----r-----
```

So when the page is refreshed, and the same file is asked to be opened with write permissions, it fails. The parent directory and the files themselves belong to `apache`. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Note: this is not a duplicate question as there is no write permission problem, the folder is writable and session files are created! The problem is that they are created with just the read-only attribute.

I changed the `session_save_path` from `/tmp` to a folder in the user's home directory. That did not help.

Every time the page is refreshed, a new session file is created because the old one can't be edited (read only). If I manually change that file to be writable, the error is gone.. Of course that's not a solution.

Comment: can you do an ls -lt on the session files ? and i guess the folder as well... I just want to see the user/owner

Comment: Don't make a new one! http://stackoverflow.com/q/27826819/3933332 You have to provide more information also include what you have tried so far! (Did you checked the permissions? Did you tried it in a new directory? Did you checked if something else is opening the files? Did you deleted it and looked if it comes again? ((Did you restarted your pc? :D sometimes it helps and also if you have a Virtual maschine can you reproduce it in there?)))

Comment: See edits above Rizier123. The other question was marked as duplicated so I deleted it. Yes I checked permissions, see above, yes tried new directory. Nothing else is opening the files. And yes, restarted. No VM.

Comment: @Wesley Please also show your script which produces this error! (The entire script!)

Comment: How is PHP being run? e.g. how is Apache configured, what platform, MPP, etc., etc? Sounds like a server configuration problem of some kind, rather than a programming issue. What user owns these session files?

Comment: Maybe the `umask` of your Apache user is creating read-only files by default. Even the owner isn't allowed to write to their own files by the permissions you listed. You should do an `ls -la /tmp`

Comment: Try this before you do session start: `ini_set('session.save_path', 'tmp');` and make sure the `tmp` folder is in root directory with chmod 777

Comment: `----r-----`? That would suggest that the session files are only even readable by the *group* that owns them, not necessarily even the user. Sounds like your server is misconfigured in some way. As @sjagr suggests, it's most likely a user or configuration umask that's gone awry. Do you have a system administrator you can discuss this with?

Comment: does parent directory have write permission?

Comment: are you running mod-php or php-fpm ?  maybe php is running as a different user which has a umask problem even if apache is fine ?